# preg_replace: making regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I know there are a lot of questions with the same problem. I read them but I couldn't fix my code.

```
<?
$tabla = "<table>
<tr>
<td>
<a class='texto'>$ 2,123.01</a>
</td>
<td>
asddasdsad$,.$$$
</td>
</tr>
</table>";
echo preg_replace("<a class='texto'>\$ ([0-9]*),([0-9]*).([0-9]*)</a>", "<a class='texto'>$0$1,$2</a>", $tabla);

?>
```

PHP Error: Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier '$'

I would like to get:

```
<?
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<a class='texto'>2123,01</a>
</td>
<td>
asddasdsad$,.$$$
</td>
</tr>
</table>
?>
```

I tried & tested my regular expression here http://regexpal.com/ and worked. But I have somthing worong in preg_replace.

Comment: you need `/` and another `/` at the very beginning and end of the regular expression

Comment: I tried but it printed the original string....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three mistakes:

1. \$ inside the double quotes means just $ which is treated by regex as match to end-of-line
2. You forgot pattern delimiters
3. $0 refers to the whole string. Expressions in parenthesis are
   referred to as $1, $2, etc.

```
echo preg_replace("|<a class='texto'>\\\$ ([0-9]*),([0-9]*).([0-9]*)</a>|", "<a class='texto'>$1$2,$3</a>", $tabla);
```

Comment: Hello @RociioLourdesRodriiguez, welcome to StackOverflow. Please consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer you found the most useful to you :)

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions need delimiters around the actual expression

```
<a class='texto'>\$ ([0-9]*),([0-9]*).([0-9]*)</a>
```

would need to be like:

```
/<a class='texto'>\$ ([0-9]*),([0-9]*).([0-9]*)<\/a>/
```

and escape any other `/` that might be in the expression

or use a different delimiter that doesnt occur in your expression

```
#<a class='texto'>\$ ([0-9]*),([0-9]*).([0-9]*)</a>#
```

<kbd>**[List of acceptable delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)**</kbd>

Comment: I tried that but it returns me the same original string. Not the expected result.

Comment: then there is other problems with your regular expression, take a look at user2755800's answer he has seem to have found further errors in your regex